# How to handle multiple react-select blocks in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I am writing a react component with two react-select fields whenever both the fields have a value I need to pass the combined object to the parent as a call back. One way I know is to store both of the options in onchange in a state and combine them and send them. However since there needs to be performance metrics I am trying to minimise re renders using state changes.

Heres a pseudo code of what I have right now. The onchange method in both sets a state but I dont want that re render to happen.

```
fieldSelectorChange = option => {
    this.setState(
      {
        option,
      },
    );
  };


<Select
      options={ fields }
      value={ sortedField }
      searchable
      placeholder={ trans( 'Find an option' ) }
      onChange={ this.fieldSelectorChange }
      autoFocus
    />
    <Select
      options={ sortOptions }
      value={ sortedOrder }
      defaultValue={ sortOptions[ 0 ] }
      placeholder={ trans( 'Choose' ) }
      onChange={ this.fieldSelectorChange }
    />
```

Comment: get real code first then we can talk. This is not specific enough. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: updated @MikeTung

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Without button

```
onSelect1Change(e) {
  this.setState({ select1value: e.target.value });
  if (this.state.select2value) {
    this.props.parentCallback({
      value1: e.target.value,
      value2: this.state.select2value
    })
  }
}

onSelect2Change(e) {
  this.setState({ select2value: e.target.value });
  if (this.state.select2value) {
    this.props.parentCallback({
      value1: this.state.select1value,
      value2: e.target.value,
    })
  }
}

/* ... */
<Select value={this.state.select1value} onChange={onSelect1Change} /* ... */ />
<Select value={this.state.select2value} onChange={onSelect2Change} /* ... */ />
```

### Without button and only one onChange

One `onSelectChange` as you asked, but in this case you recreate arrow functions every render and it's not well-optimised.

```
onSelectChange(field, value) {
  this.setState({ [field]: value });

  if (this.state.select1value && this.state.select2value) {
    this.props.parentCallback({
      value1: value,
      value2: this.state.select2value
    })
  }
}

/* ... */
<Select
  value={this.state.select1value}
  onChange={e => this.onSelectChange('select1value', e.target.value)}
  /* ... */
/>
<Select
  value={this.state.select1value}
  onChange={e => this.onSelectChange('select2value', e.target.value)}
  /* ... */
/>
```

If you want to avoid this, you have to create two more functions and use them inside of your components

```js
onSelect1Change = e => this.onSelectChange('select1value', e.target.value)
onSelect2Change = e => this.onSelectChange('select2value', e.target.value)
```

You can also add some validation here is you want:

```js
if (field in this.state) {
  this.setState({ [field]: value });
} else {
  // field is missing, do something with this case
}
```

### Form and sumbit

It's a common practive to wrap input fields in a form component.

```
onSelect1Change(e) {
  this.setState({ select1value: e.target.value });
}

onSelect2Change(e) {
  this.setState({ select2value: e.target.value });
}

onSumbit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  /* get both values from state and do something */
  console.log(this.state.select1value, this.state.select2value);
}
/* ... */
<form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
  <Select value={this.state.select1value} onChange={onSelect1Change} /* ... */ />
  <Select value={this.state.select2value} onChange={onSelect2Change} /* ... */ />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

### Button

But you can do it without form as well.
You can just make a button and get values from state on user click.

```
onSelect1Change(e) {
  this.setState({ select1value: e.target.value });
}

onSelect2Change(e) {
  this.setState({ select2value: e.target.value });
}

onClick(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  /* get both values from state and do something */
  console.log(this.state.select1value, this.state.select2value);
}
/* ... */
<div>
  <Select value={this.state.select1value} onChange={onSelect1Change} /* ... */ />
  <Select value={this.state.select2value} onChange={onSelect2Change} /* ... */ />
  <button onClick={onClick}>Click me!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thers is no submit button per se. Data must get sorted whenever there is a value. So if we select one of the dropdown and there is some value previously selected in the other select then also it should return the data in the call back

Comment: @leo okay, then you can try to you the first supposed solution

Comment: I would have used a form but since there is no on submit I dont think that I could do that.

Comment: @leo My first solution works with `this.props.parentCallback` property. If both select have  values the `parentCallback` calls :)
This solution doesn't require forms and buttons.
Note: Since we don't have centralized function to check everything, we have to check condition inside of each `onSelectChange` function.

Comment: so there is no workaround but to use two setState ?

Comment: @leo actually i have one i'll post it in my answer soon

Comment: @leo updated the answer. See "Without button and only one onChange"